# Cant get access to a folder

Tags: remote

I have copied some directories over sftp on my raspberry pi but I get strange results when trying to access them. I have changed the owner to pi with this command:

```
sudo chown pi libs/ --recursive
```

but I cant access chmod without using sudo like this: `chmod 0644 libs --recursive` and even if I execute this as super user, I still have no access to my directory. Where is the problem?

Comment: Note the name of a file/directory you can't access and do an `ls -l` on its parent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What probably happens is, that your directory `libs` gets chmodded first. Chmodding recursively always requires a bit of attention.

To have access to a directory, it must be executable for you. 0644 means that the directory is not executable, and therefore not accessible.

Instead of your recursive `chmod` try the following:

```
find libs -type d -exec chmod 0755 {} \;
find libs -type f -exec chmod 0644 {} \;
```

`type d` means directories; `type f` means all files.